# How to query two tables to get user that hasn't voted?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm stuck doing this sql query....I have two tables one with all my users and another one with votes per user.
I want to check the users that hasn't voted.
I'm trying some like this but is not working.

```
usuarios table 
----------------------
| id      | username |
----------------------

votes 
--------------------------------------------
|  id     | user     | mes       | ano     |



SELECT DISTINCT a.username 
FROM usuarios a
     , votes b 
WHERE a.username != b.user 
AND b.ano = 2019 
AND b.mes = 11


on my usuarios table i hvae 20 entries.

1 | user1
2 | user2
........

on my votes table 
1 | user1 | 11 | 2019
```

and with the query I want to get only the users from(usuarios table) that are not on my votes table;

Comment: Can you show us some data ? One or two rows of what you want to get and what you get now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description translates to a *Correlated Subquery* using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT a.username 
FROM usuarios a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM votes b 
   WHERE a.username = b.user -- no vote from this user
     AND b.ano = 2019        -- in this year
     AND b.mes = 1           -- and month
 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend for you help, and thanks for let it me know what type of query i have to do....some new to learn

Answer (score 2):

Just use a left JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.username FROM usuarios a
LEFT JOIN votes b 
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.user is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on SQL version, you will have something like this.  MS SQL would be this, but other versions of SQL will be very similar:

```
SELECT * 
FROM USARIOS A
  LEFT JOIN
  VOTES B
  ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.USER IS NULL
```